# How long can you keep yeasted waffle batter (including eggs/buttermilk) in the refrigerator?

Tags: batter, pancakes, breakfast, waffle

How long can you keep yeasted waffle batter (including eggs/buttermilk) in the refrigerator?

Comment: First thought... "until it grows out of the bowl"... but that's a joke. I've never used yeast-based waffle batter, only chemically leavened stuff... which has a similar question [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13287/how-long-does-pancake-batter-last-in-the-fridge), which I'm linking for reference purposes.

Comment: Are you asking out of concerns for food safety reasons or the viability of the batter to successfully turn into a pancake when cooked?