# Can you save pancake batter for one day?

Tags: storage, batter, pancakes

I only need a few pancakes at a time. I would rather cook fresh than freeze cooked pancakes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing cake batter](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41959/storing-cake-batter). Pancake batter or cake batter it's the same thing with the same answer.

Comment: What type of pancake?  There’s an older question about British pancakes

Comment: American pancakes: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13287/67 ; British pancakes : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12933/67 ; when it’s probably too long : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/52153/67

Comment: You will lose leavening and the batter will make tough pancakes after a day. A better option is to cook a bunch and refrigerate them, they'll keep for several days and they microwave well. Freezing makes them tough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mix the dry ingredients and mix the wet ingredients, but store the mixes separately. When you want to cook some pancakes, take (e.g.) 1/3 of each of the mixes, mix them together, and then cook them. This means you don't lose the leavening power and your main time constraint is how long an egg-milk mixture will last in the fridge.

The question @GdG linked to has an answer suggesting something similar for cakes, but it doesn't work for many cakes since there isn't a clear wet-dry separation up to the last step.

Comment: Also storing wet and dry separately helps avoid gluten development in the batter, which can make pancakes tough.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you refrigerate, it will be fine for 3 or 4 days, though the leavening power will likely reduce over time.